# Workflow to encrypt files I use in a text editor

Tags: encryption, sublime-text-2

People say it is a good idea to encrypt your file system and/or encrypt files. I'm wondering how I do this with Sublime Text editor. I'm wondering if I need to do this, essentially:

1. Encrypt all files in folder, recursively, using AES-256
2. Unencrypt the current file I am working on.
3. Make some changes.
4. Rencrypt.

That is a lot of work and I would like to know what an easier way to manage it is. It doesn't allow for searching the files, for example. So I would like to know how to encrypt text files I would like to work on regularly, doing searching with grep (or a grep alternative) and other things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the files to remain encrypted, and not leave decrypted files (even deleted = easily undelete-able files) lying around, then just encrypt your entire filesystem, and swap. Many programs leave temporary copies of files lying around everywhere.

Or use a small encrypted container like LUKS or Veracrypt, that would avoid having your decrypted files on the drive, but programs still might create temporary / cache copies in other places.

Or a file encryption system like eCryptfs or EncFS (same program warning as above).

Or BitLocker (it can do an entire system).

If you just wanted to casually encrypt a file or two, you could use something like GPG (PGP), but the original & unencrypted files would still be lying around the drive (unless they were wiped, and that's not always 100% effective).

Also worth mentioning, running your entire OS in RAM (off of a live linux ISO/USB/DVD, *with no persistence*) would avoid leaving any unencrypted files behind.